# Attaching an UIimage behind a UItexView in tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimageview, autolayout

I have attached a UItextView in tableview cell. Now I want to insert an UIimage behind it like a chat bubble.But everytime I scroll the tableview ,  the Uitextview becomes smaller in width and longer in height. The text also gets resized from single to multi line. Also ,the same thing happens when I scroll back to an earlier cell ( for example the first row).
I can't figure out why this is happening.

My code is: 
(**SampleTableViewCell** is my custom UItableViewCell class and **lblTitle** is my UitextView outlet.)

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: SampleTableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) 
 {

    cell.lblTitle.removeConstraints(cell.lblTitle.constraints)

    let stringTitle = carName[indexPath.row] as String //carName is an array
    cell.lblTitle.text=stringTitle
    cell.lblTitle.sizeToFit()

    let h = cell.lblTitle.frame.size.height
    let w = cell.lblTitle.frame.size.width
    let constraints = NSLayoutConstraint(item: cell.lblTitle, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: cell.lblTitle, attribute: .Height, multiplier: 0, constant: w)
    cell.lblTitle.addConstraint(constraints)

    let kl = UIImage(imageLiteral: "bubble")
    let imageView  = UIImageView(frame:CGRectMake(0, 0, w, h))
    imageView.image = kl
    imageView.alpha = 0.4
    cell.lblTitle.addSubview(imageView)
    cell.lblTitle.sendSubviewToBack(imageView)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is the problem of autolayout.

You are just giving height and width constraint to textView. what about x and y position?

And you haven't set constraints for your imageview!!

If you are giving constraint to one object then you required to give every object related to it.

So set proper constraints and your problem will be solved.

Comment: I have already defined the size of uiImageView while creating it. the problem is everytime I scroll w and h changes. Will it solve the problem if I set a trailing constraint in UItextview with the super view.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding bubble imageview and constraints programmatically,using storyboard you can add imageview in the tableview cell first and then UITextView of same size as imageview and add constraints.Then you can add your logic at cellForRowAtIndexPath delegate for lblTitle's text and bubble image. Make sure to set lblTitle's background to ClearColor.

Comment: But my uitextview size is going to change according to its content. How will I change my imageview accordingly.